# How can Content Security Policy default-src: none can be fixed for a React app?

Tags: reactjs, express, content-security-policy

I have tried to recreate a React app of mine that was done with create-react-app, with my own webpack settings and configuration. Everything was working fine until I hit Content Security Policy issues as this:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ThhI8UaSFEbbl6cISiZpnJ4Z44uNSq2tPKgyRTD3LyU='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have tried to set the CSP header in metatags with different arguments in the projects public/index/html but to no result. And sometimes the page wasn't even showing.

Answer (score 0):

There are most likely two issues:

1. A Content Security Policy value of 'none' means that *no* resources are allowed to be loaded. You'll need to include all resources that your app requires within the content security policy. There are tools such as these [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/csp-generator/)/[chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/content-security-policy-c/ahlnecfloencbkpfnpljbojmjkfgnmdc) extensions for automatically building policies.
2. You'll need to move all inline content (embedded in any HTML) to its own javascript file. A guide can be found [here](https://csper.io/docs/guide-removing-inline).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
default-src 'none'
```

you may try

```
default-src 'self'
```

This will enable CSP to use its own scripts, styles, fonts, images, etc. It is recommended to define policies more specifically; in your case, it complains with scripts, so you would normally add as well:

```
script-src 'self'
```